# How to resolve promises using $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI router's $state.go('myStateName') to navigate to a new state. **How can I pass in promises that will be resolved?**

This is similar to the $stateProvider.state definition where you can specify a list of promises that must be resolved prior to state change, but the difference here is that my controller calling $state.go needs to pass in the promise. In other words, I can't specify the promise in the state definition's 'resolve' property because the promise is not known until runtime.

**Why don't I resolve the promises prior to calling $state.go()?** Because I like how $state.go will remove the old template, and the new template and controller do not show up until the state's "resolve"s have been resolved. I'm after the UX. I don't want my users waiting on the same page while I resolve out promises prior to navigating to the new page. I could show a spinner so they know something is happening, but I'd rather do this by removing the old template.

Comment: You can specify a promise that resolves with the actual promise as soon it is known?

Comment: Resolve promise then call `$state.go()`. Can pass data parameters to `$state.go()` also. A better explanation of the issue would help

Comment: @charlietfl this is *almost* exactly what I need. Updates to the question to show why this won't completely work for me.

Comment: Not hard to hide UI in either the current or the next state ..  or `ng-if` to not even generate UI.

Comment: One module I like using is `cg-busy`. Uses promises to manage loading indicator, UI visibility etc

Comment: I'm using animations to swap the templates in and out, so it is much more visible to our user than the case you present. Being creative with the CSS and DOM structure I'm sure I could have mitigated this, but this isn't really an option this far into the project.

Comment: @charlietfl cg-busy is awesome! This is much better than the one I am currently using. Thanks for sharing

Comment: I like it...it is sooo simple to use